# How to created visualization dashboard for summary data?

Tags: graphics, data, visualization

I would like to create the following dashboard:

[image: DashboardDesign]

The numbers indicate my desired dimensions for the cells. I would like the cells to contain a regional plot, a trend line, and bar charts. I have tried to map the design with GraphicsRow, GraphicsColumn, and GraphicsGrid. Thus far the best I've been able to do is:

```
g1 = Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]];
g2 = Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]];
g3 = Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 4}]];
gg1 = GraphicsGrid[{{GraphicsGrid[{{g1}, {g2}}, Frame -> All], g3}}, 
  Frame -> All]
```

Which produces:

[image: Trail1]

and

```
g6 = Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]];
g3 = Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 4}]];
g7 = Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 5}]];
GraphicsRow[{GraphicsColumn[{g6, g3}, Frame -> All], g7}]
```

which gave:

[image: trial2]

I've thought about using Inset, but I'm not sure that will work? What else can I try? Is Mathematica really what I want to use? I've helped in designing a dashboard in R, and it seemed quite painful.

Comment: Re: _" Is Mathematica really what I want to use?"_ is a very difficult question to answer ... for _me_ :)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I should have asked: What other programs could produce this? In fact, I prefer to use Mathematica. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x = Graphics[Circle[]];
{spa, spl, spb} = {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromBoth};
GraphicsGrid[{
  {x,   x,   x,   x  },
  {x,   spl, x,   spa}, 
  {spa, spb, spa, spa}, 
  {x,   spl, spa, spa}, 
  {spa, spb, spa, spa}
  }, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Have you tried it with `Graphics` like rectangles that have the correct size? http://i.stack.imgur.com/GnBhR.png (In case you like the code: `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/fPqOg.png"]`)

Comment: @halirutan Looks like the OP will try to put different kinds of objects inside the grid. I don't believe that trying to adjust the whole thing to rectangles right now is going to relief his final tuning.

Comment: @halirutan In any case, please try your code with `Alignment -> Top`

Comment: OK, this is typical for WRI. Why should alignment be important for items that fit perfectly? *sign*

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer since it was the exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the tools in the menu to build whatever shape you need:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like the generality of this approach. I would say that it was a bit tricky to follow the video mostly because my right-click option did not work the same as on the video. For others in my situation you can go to the Insert option next to the right of File and Edit, and then click on Table/Matrix. First I made the table and then going back to that Table/Matrix I was able to select "Make Spanning".